# Get a link id from a php link button

Tags: php, button, hyperlink

Hi this is aa part of my php file.

```
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$query  = "SELECT * FROM promoter";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border=\"2\">\n"; 
echo "   <tr>\n"; 
echo "      <th>Id</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>User Id</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>Full Name</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>Qualification</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Locality</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Description</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Language</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Bank Details</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Change</th>\n";


echo "    </tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
print "<tr> <td>";
    echo $row['id']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['user_id']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['full_name']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['qualification'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['locality'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['description'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['language'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['bank_details'];
    print "</td> <td>";
     //echo '<a href="update.php" >Modi</a>';
    echo '<a href="update.php" id= "<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Modify</a>';
    print "</td> </tr>";

}



echo " </table>\n";
include 'closedb.php';
```

I want to get the row id of the of the table row when the button is link is clicked. How can i get that? There is a link for every row of the table , so when the link is clicked it should take the row ['id'] as the id value , so every link has the id value of its row id.

Comment: Remove the php tag and write: '. $row["id"].'

Comment: You want to get the `row id` value when someone click? You must use javascript to do that. `click` is an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
    print "<tr> <td>";
    echo $row['id']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['user_id']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['full_name']; 
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['qualification'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['locality'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['description'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['language'];
    print "</td> <td>";
    echo $row['bank_details'];
    print "</td> <td>";
     //echo '<a href="update.php" >Modi</a>';
    echo '<a href="update.php?id= "'.$row['id'].'">Modify</a>';
    print "</td> </tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
(in your php file)
echo '<a href="update.php" id= ".$row['id']." onclick="getId(this)">Modify</a>';

<script>
function getId(link){
    alert(link.id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can work with multiple types of `requests`. The two most common ones are `POST` and `GET` requests.

The `GET` request is the one that is being done to the server when you normally click a link.

#### Example

```
<a href="index.php?id=1">Click me</a>

<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])): ?>
    The requested id is <?= $_GET['id']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the above example we are requesting `index.php` with the `GET` parameter `id`. PHP stores these parameters in the superglobal `$_GET`.

In your case:

```
while (...) {
    echo "<a href='modify.php?id='".$row['id']."'>Modify</a>";
}
```